# Android - Two buttons in Linear Layout not getting displayed

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have an activity where I define two buttons at the bottom of the activity. Surprisingly, the two buttons are not getting displayed. Not able to get to know why they are not getting displayed. Below is the XML file

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#1caff4"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="center">

 <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/Dummy1"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"

            /> 
              <TextView
            android:layout_width = "fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="65sp"
            android:text="@string/logo"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"                        
 ></TextView>




<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

   >

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/ViewMessageOne"               
            android:layout_width="285dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:padding="5dp"               
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:typeface="sans" 
            android:background="@drawable/back"             
            android:gravity="center"
            />   


        <ImageView               
            android:id="@+id/infoimage"             
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"            
            android:src="@drawable/banner_portrait"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ViewMessageOne"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"              
            android:layout_height="40dp"            
           />   

        </LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"   
   >

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/CreateMessage"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0.2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_corner"
            android:text="@string/CreateMessage"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"               
            android:textSize="20sp"></Button>

      <Button
            android:id="@+id/MyMessages"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"         
            android:background="@drawable/button_corner"
            android:text="@string/MyMessages"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"               
            android:textSize="20sp"
             ></Button> 

</LinearLayout>
```

The buttons are with id CreateMessage and MyMessages. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your layout_height="fill_parent", thats the reason. Put wrap_content.

Comment: change your linear layout height to android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: Replace your layout_height="fill_parent" with android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

only change second LinearLayout Height to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and also your last LinearLayout Height to the `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: I am now able to see the buttons. Thanks. But the linear layout which was at the center of the activity has now come down. Any idea?

Comment: ok Remove margintop="170dp" from your "Dummy1" textview and see what happen?

Answer (score 2):

Please remove `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`  for child layouts and use wrap_content.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your second `LinearLayout` has `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` so it will occupy all the space .Try using

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

or

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

which will first assign space to the other `View` and lastly give whatever space is remaining to the second `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 1):

Please remove `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` of your child Linearlayout and use

`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.